# css label for checkbox need to specify for single class

Tags: javascript, css

In my CSS file I have a setting for some checkbox labels such as:

```css
.checkboxes label:hover, input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}
```

I only want this setting for checkboxes where I'm using the class above
.checkboxes

However, this affects all my input type="checkbox" if I use a label with the checkbox.

What do I need to do so that I only use this style if I am using the class above.
i.e  class="checkboxes"

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: this is the full settings I have in my CSS file for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.checkboxes` to the front of the second selector:

`.checkboxes label:hover, .checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}`

Comment: That fixed it, I knew I was doing something wrong. Thanks very much.